# IPythonで実行したコードに対して、DeprecationWarningを表示する方法

Tags: python, ipython

## 環境

- Python3.7

## やりたいこと

IPython上でコードを実行したとき、DeprecationWarningを表示するようにしたいです。
実行時、警告に気づくようにするためです。
たとえば、以下の`get_history`メソッドを実行したときです。

```py
class SampleApi:
    def get_history(self, history_id):
        warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
        return history_id
```

どのような操作を行えば、IPythonで実行したときに警告が表示されるようになりますか？
私の環境では、DeprecationWarningが表示されませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の記事は逆に警告を表示させない方法の質問ですが、自己解決していて、
かつ回答の中に警告の出し方を変える方法の補足があります。
[Hide all warnings in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9031783/9014308)
質問：

> 私はipythonセッションのスクリーンキャストを作成する必要があります、そして混乱する視聴者を避けるために、私は異なるパッケージからの`warnings.warn`呼び出しによって発せられるすべての警告を無効にしたいです。 このような警告をすべて自動的に無効にするように`ipythonrc`ファイルを構成する方法はありますか？

回答：

> 私は結局それを考え出した。

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

> `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/disable-warnings.py`の中。
>   他の誰かが同じ問題に遭遇した場合に備えて、私はこの質問と回答を残しています。
>   多くの場合、一度警告を表示すると便利です。
>   これは次のように設定できます。

```
warnings.filterwarnings(action='once')
```

---

仕様の詳細は以下にあって、デフォルトでは`DeprecationWarning`は`ignore`になっているようです。
下記仕様に記載されたいずれかの方法で`DeprecationWarning`を有効にすれば良いと思われます。

[warnings --- 警告の制御](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/warnings.html)
[警告フィルタ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)
[Default Warning Filter](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filter)

> デフォルトでは、Pythonはいくつかの警告フィルタをインストールします。
>   これらは、`-W`コマンドラインオプション、`PYTHONWARNINGS`環境変数、および`filterwarnings()`への呼び出しによって上書きされます。
>   通常のリリースビルドでは、デフォルトの警告フィルタに次のエントリがあります（優先順位の高い順）。
>   default::DeprecationWarning:__main__
>   ignore::DeprecationWarning
>   ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
>   ignore::ImportWarning
>   ignore::ResourceWarning